# Chartjs line chart from array of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, chart.js, line

I have an array of dates on column 6 of my datatable in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and I need to plot a line chart using chartjs similar to this one: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line.html .
I have some datasets (project1, project2, project3, etc) and I would like to count the daily occurencies for each dataset on the same linechart like in the example above.
Here's part of my code:

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
var dateCol= $('tr>td:nth-child(7)');

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['total project1 issues'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Project1 issues distribution',
            data: [dateCol],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',

            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',

            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,

        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
            type: 'time'
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}); 
} //go on with project 2, project3, and so on
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
moment.js:283 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: total projects issues, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
```

Here's the code I'm using for the selection of a specific project, but this counts overall the whole datatable and not day by day:

```
  $("#select").val("project1").trigger("change");
  project1= table.page.info().recordsDisplay;
```

Where am I wrong?
Thank you very much

EDIT: I managed to get a total number of occurrences per project, but I still can't find them daily. How can I parse the date column and count, for each day, how many occurrencies I have?

EDIT: here's the html table from which I need to create the linechart:

```
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>software name</th>
      <th>windows version</th>
      <th>2020-09-01</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-01</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-02</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>2020-09-03</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-04</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-05</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>winVista</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>2020-09-06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>2020-09-07</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>2020-09-07</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT2: I managed to perform some tweaks to the code like selecting only YYYY-MM-DD but the error remains the same

Comment: the moment **error** you are mentioning is actually a **warning**. can you share more code regarding your datatable since if i understood correctly then it seems you have issue with aggregating data from table based on dates.

Comment: @sandeepjoshi added the html table. Is there a way to create a linechart like the one in the link above?